# Calculating the coefficient of concordance for vague data

Tags: statistics, correlation

I'm trying to adapt a formula that calculates the coefficient of concordance for vague data. The paper that describes it is here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4738093_The_coefficient_of_concordance_for_vague_data

The specific equation I'm interested in is (22) [which I've linked to here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMNCE.jpg)

I can work out the equation in R for the standard equation of Kendall's W but not this one. I think I'm just messing up the order of operations.

In R it looks like the input values should be:

```
u <- c(6/7, 4/7, 1, 1/7, 2/7, 3/7, 5/7, 0,
    5/7, 4/7, 6/7, 1/7, 2/7, 3/7, 0, 0,
        1, 5/7, 2/7, 0, 2/7, 4/7, 6/7, 1/7,
            5/7, 3/7, 4/7, 0, 2/7, 0, 6/7, 1/7)
v<-c(1/7, 3/7, 0, 6/7, 5/7, 4/7, 2/7, 1,
    1/7, 2/7, 0, 5/7, 4/7, 3/7, 0, 6/7,
        0, 2/7, 4/7, 1, 4/7, 3/7, 1/7, 6/7,
            1/7, 3/7, 2/7, 6/7, 4/7, 0, 0, 5/7)
```

Hope you can help

Comment: In my opinion many on this site are too eager to refer real-data questions to `http://stats.stackexchange.com/`, but I think this question is more likely to get an answer there--both because of its applied nature and because the solution will require advanced programming knowledge.

Comment: I take your point, but I was having trouble getting the correct answer irrespective of the coding problem.

Comment: I am not sure whether any software package has a programmed procedure for finding this measure of concordance. If not, and if this is a generally useful descriptive measure, then I suppose it will appear in an R library, or in similar freeware. That is more likely to happen if the audience at the affiliated `stats` website sees your question.